# Space-specific Confluence link

Tags: confluence

We have lot of links to our svn in Confluence pages that are of format http://svn.ourdomain.com/java/project/trunk/folder/SomeFile.java. When we make an export of confluence pages, we'd want all those links to change to http://svn.ourdomain.com/java/project/tags/1.5/folder/SomeFile.java, and after that we'd like to be able to revert the links back to pointing to trunk. It's a pain to change hundreds or thousands of links to point to specific version.

Is there a way to do this? Somehow configurable url template, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the original links used shortcut links, you could change the shortcut to reference the specific tag for the export then back to trunk again after the export.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+Shortcut+Links

For example:

1. Configure a shortcut:

   **Key:** `svn`

   **Expanded Value:** `http://svn.ourdomain.com/java/project/trunk/`
2. Replace links in pages with the following and adopt this standard going forward:

   ```
   [folder/SomeFile.java@svn]
   ```
3. Reconfigure the shortcut:

   **Key:** `svn`

   **Expanded Value:** `http://svn.ourdomain.com/java/project/tags/1.5/`
4. Export the space.
5. Restore the shortcut to the original expanded value - step 1 above.